# What is "dray bid"

Tags: word-meaning

In the "Seventeen" by Booth Tarkington there is a certain miss who likes to lisp constantly.

She addresses to a dog in the following manner:

> Oh, nassy dray bid Horror!

*Nassy* apparently means "nasty", but what is *dray bid* ?

Few lines below she is using the same expression in a good sense:

> we had a nice dray bid MANS to protect us

The full context is:

> “Oh, nassy dray bid Horror!” cried his mistress, turning quickly at this sound and waving a pink parasol at Clematis. “Shoo! DIRTY dog! Go 'way!” And she was able somehow to connect him with the wash-tub and boiler, for she added, “Nassy laundrymans to have bad doggies!”
>
> Mr. Watson rushed upon Clematis with angry bellowings and imaginary missiles. “You disgusting brute!” he roared. “How DARE you?”
>
> Apparently much alarmed, Clematis lowered his ears, tucked his tail underneath him, and fled to the rear, not halting once or looking back until he disappeared round the corner whence he had come. “There!” said Mr. Watson. “I guess HE won't bother us again very soon!”
>
> It must be admitted that Milady was one of those people who do not mind being overheard, no matter what they say. “Lucky for us,” she said, “we had a nice dray bid MANS to protect us, wasn't it, Flopit?” And she thought it necessary to repeat something she had already made sufficiently emphatic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about text that's over a century old, and full of (probably inaccurately conceived / rendered) slang / dialect / speech impediments. It clearly isn't a suitable text for people wishing to learn current English.

Comment: I don't know this author, but the fragments cited above lead me to suppose he was deliberately poking fun at negroes because they didn't speak ***his*** kind of English. Introducing a character with an actual speech impediment is just piling on the agony.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then you've also got over 500 questions about Shakespeare and over 100 about the King James Bible to get closed, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my humble opinion the good command of English may also include some understanding of old and/or non-textbook sources.

Comment: I agree. A person can be learning English at an advanced level and Booth Tarkington would be, in that sense, just like Dickens.

Comment: No disrespect, @YuriyZhilovets, but your definite article after *In my humble opinion* is all the evidence I need to be quite certain you should devote far more time to learning "normal, current" English. People may upvote your comment for ideological reasons, but I can't believe anyne who knows what they're talking about would do so for ***pedagogical*** reasons. It's not even as useful as studying Latin to help understand English, since there will be next to nothing in Tarkington's entire output that has meaningfully influenced current English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "here will be next to nothing in Tarkington's entire output that has meaningfully influenced current English" -- F.S. Fitzerald does not agree with you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is phonetic representation of the Lola character's 'baby talk'

> An aspiring actress, Lola is a "howling belle of eighteen" who talks
> baby-talk "even at breakfast"

[Seventeen (Tarkington novel - Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_(Tarkington_novel))

The William character spends the summer pursuing Lola. His family and friends do not share his high opinion of his "babytalk lady".

In the 1910s and 1920s Tarkington was considered the United States' 'greatest living author' (it says in Wikipedia).

A Google search for `"dray bid" Booth Tarkington` shows a number of quotes where, for example, a young female person is referred to in this type of speech as a 'dirl', so we have d for g. So 'gray big', which (I think) is clearly 'great big' which very much fits the context.

These days there is much in Tarkington that is unbearable to a modern sensibility, the heavy use of phonetic dialect and odd speech, and especially, and notoriously, that invented by him and put into the mouths of those of his characters he called 'Negroes'. Dialect of the 'Sho-nuff Massa!' type.

Comment: Thank you for a small historical language journey. I am now translating this book. "Negroes speech" is clearly untranslatable but "dray bid" after your clarification still has some chances.

Comment: Tarkington's black dialect attempts: "their language sounds like the worst kind of vaudeville blackface impersonation. (“I guess I uz dess talkin’ whens I said ’at! Reckon he thought I meant it, f’m de way he tuck an’ run. Hiyi! Reckon he thought ole Herman bad man! No, suh, I uz dess talkin’, ’cause I nev’ would cut nobody! I ain’ tryin’ git in no jail—no, suh!”)" - a _New Yorker_ article. That type of speech is understandable, sadly, even today. I think 'translating' it would be a specialised task.

Comment: Surely I want to render it somehow. Her baby talk very precisely characterizes this girl. To omit it is to deprive the text and to lose some funny moments.

Comment: Oh yes, and let's get rid of Mark Twain also. Throw 'em all out I say. Dickens, too.

Comment: @YuriyZhilovets: "Negroes speech" is clearly ***syntactic garbage***, on a par with, say, ***Irishmen speech***.

Comment: You are, presumably, keeping the baby talk? It won't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You suppose that Tarkington's rendition of blacks' oral language of 1916 was not very accurate? I will keep it in mind, thank you.

Comment: @YuriyZhilovets: Booth Tarkington came from a privileged wealthy white background. I'm guessing his family didn't keep black slaves, so he probably didn't have much direct experience of how they spoke. His renditions are primarily just (ignorant, but to some extent unintentional) caricatures. But whatever his motivation over a century ago, the net effect today, as Michael points out, is it's "the worst kind of vaudeville blackface impersonation". I wouldn't dignify it with any credibility.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'I'm guessing his family didn't keep black slaves' - since slavery was outlawed in Indiana at the time of granting of statehood in in 1816, and Booth was born in 1869, I think that is pretty likely.

Comment: @YuriyZhilovets Caricatures are based on fact, but they exaggerate it for humorous purposes. This is not politically correct these days, and a book like this would not be received well now (similar to why Disney no longer makes "Song of the South" available).

Answer (score 1):

"Dray bid" must be baby talk for "great big."

Reddit chat rooms with people pretending to post as the speech of cats and kittens shows the same kind of over-the-top distortion of language.